# How do we derive the expression for $e^x$ from $e$?

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function, proof-explanation

Trying to go in historical order here and begin with Bernoulli's formulation for $e$:

$$e = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n$$

How do we then make the jump to

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + x/n)^n$$

I had tried doing this:

$$e^x = (\lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^n)^x$$

$$e^x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 1/n)^{nx}$$

Let $m = nx$ so $n = m/x$. As $n$ goes to infinity, $m$ also goes to infinity, so:

$$e^x = \lim_{m \to \infty} (1 + x/m)^{m}$$

(although we could relabel with $n=m$ I just use $m$ to use a different one)

But I was told that I'm skipping many unproven assumptions doing this. Is there an easy way to prove what I am missing or is there an easier way to arrive at the result?

Comment: Obvious weak points are taking the exponent $x$ inside the limit and replacing $m=nx$ which assumes that $x>0$

Comment: I guess that "skipping many unproven assumptions" would fit well with historical order ...

Comment: I think one point could be made that real exponentiation is **defined** by the exponential function. So you could only use your proof for integer, or at most rational $x$

Comment: The index $m$ should be positive integer if it's a limit of a *sequence*.  Otherwise, extend the sequence to continuous function defined for all $n\in\Bbb R_+$.

Comment: The only critical step is to justify that the power of the limit is the limit of the power. If logarithms are allowed, they turn the problem to that of the limit of a product (using continuity of the logarithm).

Answer (score 4):

In what follows $n$ denotes a positive integer. This is a typical / conventional use of symbol $n$.

Using a little bit of algebra you can show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=e^{x}\tag{1}$$ where $x$ is rational and $e$ is defined by $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\tag{2}$$ Let's first assume that $x$ is a positive integer and then $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=\left(\frac{n+x} {n} \right) ^n=\prod_{k=1}^{x}\left(\frac{n+k}{n+k-1}\right)^n\\=\prod_{k=1}^{x}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+k-1}\right)^{n+k-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{n+k-1}\right)^{1-k}$$ The first factor in the product on right tends to $e$ and second factor tends to $1$ so that the desired limit is $\prod_{k=1}^{x}e=e^x$. If $x=-y$ is a negative integer then we have $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{y}\dfrac{1}{\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-k}\right)^{n-k}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n-k}\right)^{k}}$$ and thus the desired limit is $1/e^{y}=e^x$.

For $x=0$ the result is obvious and thus we have established $(1)$ when $x$ is an integer. If $x$ is a rational number say $p/q$ where $p$ is an integer and $q$ is a positive integer then $$\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{n}=\sqrt[q]{\left(1+\frac{p}{qn}\right)^{qn}}$$ which tends to $\sqrt[q]{e^{p}} =e^x$ and our proof is complete. This step involves the continuity of function $f(t) =t^{1/q}$ and should be available to you already (this can also be proved using some algebraic manipulation).

For irrational $x$ we need a definition of irrational exponents and the proof depends on the chosen definition. The result holds even when $x$ is a complex number but the proof requires somewhat different tools (but again limited to basic algebraic manipulation).

Comment: Very nice! thus the proof by continuity is not correct in this case and that we need to refer to more basic properties?

Comment: I don't really follow this answer at all, I don't understand this product expansion or what it's meant to illustrate, we sort of jump right to $(1+x/n)^n$ without any real reason for doing so prior.

Comment: @user535250: write the product in full and you will understand it.

Comment: @user535250: for $x=2$ we have $(1+2/n)^n=((n+2)/n)^n=((n+2)/(n+1))^n((n+1)/n)^n$ both factors tend to $e$ and hence limit is $ee=e^2$

Comment: @gimusi : issue with your proof is that $k= n/x$ is not necessarily an integer.

Comment: @user535250: I have added one more step for you to get the product. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly observe that for $y\in \mathbb{R}\quad y\to +\infty$ with $y\in(n,n+1)$

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n=\frac{ \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1} }{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)}\le\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y\le\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$

thus for squeeze theorem

$$\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^y\to e$$

It easy to see that the same limit holds also for $y\in \mathbb{R}\quad y\to -\infty$.

Then note that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ fixed, since $y=\frac{n}{x}\to \pm\infty\,$ by continuity and algebraic rules for limits we have that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}x}\right]^x=\left[\lim_{y \to \pm\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{y}\right)^{y}\right]^x\to e^x$$

For $x=0 \implies e^0 = \lim_{n \to \infty} (1 + 0/n)^n=1$.

Thus the identity holds $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: That doesn't show how it comes from $e$ though

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't get what you are looking for, but the inner limit is the definition of e and for continuity the limit holds.

Comment: @user535250 Think to x as a fixed value.

Comment: @YvesDaoust yes of course, I fix!

Comment: The OP already knows about the transformation to move the variable to the exponent. The answer should focus on justifying that the exponent can "cross" the limit.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Sorry what do you mean by "cross" the limit?

Comment: @gimusi: well, that doesn't appear on your post as you avoided writing the limits ans skipped a step.

Comment: This is fine but needs the definition of irrational exponents beforehand.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh There was also a minor issu for the case $y\to -\infty$. For the definition of irrational exponent I will use the standard trick to assume that as a given result :)

Comment: Don't worry about negative $x$ that's easily handled by the limit $(1-x^2/n^2)^n\to 1$ using Bernoulli inequality. And +1 already given.

Answer (score 0):

Given
$$
n \in \mathbb N \quad x,r \in \mathbb R  \quad 0<y \in \mathbb R
$$

we have
$$
e = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{n\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {1 \over n}} \right)^{\,n}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {1 \over x}} \right)^{\,x} 
$$
and then 
$$
\eqalign{
  & e^{\,y}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {1 \over x}} \right)^{\,x\,y}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {y \over {x\,y}}} \right)^{\,x\,y}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\,y\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {y \over {x\,y}}} \right)^{\,x\,y}  =   \cr 
  &  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {y \over r}} \right)^{\,r}  \cr} 
$$

and also
$$
\eqalign{
  & e^{\, - y}  = {1 \over {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 + {1 \over x}} \right)^{\,\,x\,y} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 - {1 \over {1 + x}}} \right)^{\,\,x\,y}  = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 - {1 \over {1 + x}}} \right)^{\,\,\left( {1 + x\,} \right)y - y}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\mathop {\lim }\limits_{1 + x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 - {1 \over {1 + x}}} \right)^{\,\,\left( {1 + x\,} \right)y} } \over {\mathop {\lim }\limits_{1 + x\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 - {1 \over {1 + x}}} \right)^{\,\,y} }} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{r\, \to \,\infty } \left( {1 - {y \over r}} \right)^{\,\,r}  \cr} 
$$